# Crash when connecting to Bluetooth device via WinAPI Socket (Access violation reading location 0x00000004)

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, visual-c++, bluetooth

I think you are my last hope. I have got here a Bluetooth device (it is a sensor to be more precisely) which I want to connect to and read data from. The device offers SPP (Serial Port Profile). To avoid the problem of reliable mapping from Bluetooth addresses and virtual serial ports (COM Ports), I am going to use sockets.

Unfortunately the application always crashes before returning from WinAPI function **connect**(...) with:  *0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004*, so I get **no error code**.

**BUT, and that is weird, when I right-click on the Bluetooth System Tray Icon to to show available devices, my device shows up being authenticated and connected.** This list was empty before, of course.

My OS is Windows 7 64 Bit, the IDE is Visual Studio 2010, Microsoft Bluetooth Stack. Code to find and connect to my only device:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2bth.h>



BOOL auth_callback_ex(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS authParams)
{
    BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE response;
    response.bthAddressRemote = authParams->deviceInfo.Address;
    response.authMethod = authParams->authenticationMethod; // == BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_LEGACY

    UCHAR pin[] = "1234";
    std::copy(pin, pin+sizeof(pin), response.pinInfo.pin);
    response.pinInfo.pinLength = sizeof(pin)-1; //excluding '\0'

    response.negativeResponse = false;


    HRESULT err = BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx(NULL, &response);
    if (err)
    {
        std::cout << "BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx error = " << err << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS btSearchParams;

    btSearchParams.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS);
    btSearchParams.cTimeoutMultiplier = 5;  //5*1.28s search timeout
    btSearchParams.fIssueInquiry = true;    //new inquiry

    //return all known and unknown devices
    btSearchParams.fReturnAuthenticated = true;
    btSearchParams.fReturnConnected = true;
    btSearchParams.fReturnRemembered = true;
    btSearchParams.fReturnUnknown = true;

    btSearchParams.hRadio = NULL;   //search on all local radios



    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDeviceInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&btDeviceInfo, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));   //"initialize"

    btDeviceInfo.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND btDeviceFindHandle = NULL;

    btDeviceFindHandle = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&btSearchParams, &btDeviceInfo);
    if(btDeviceFindHandle)
    {

        HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION authCallbackHandle = NULL;

        DWORD err = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(&btDeviceInfo, &authCallbackHandle, &auth_callback_ex, NULL);


        if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication Error" << err << std::endl; 
        }

        /////////////// Socket
        WSADATA wsaData;
        err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (err)
        {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup error = " << err << std::endl;
        }


        // create BT socket
        SOCKET s = socket (AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
        assert(s != INVALID_SOCKET);    //WSAGetLastError //throw // runtime check release?

        SOCKADDR_BTH btSockAddr;
        btSockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
        btSockAddr.btAddr = btDeviceInfo.Address.ullLong;
        btSockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID; //SerialPortServiceClass_UUID (no difference)
        btSockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;


        err = connect(s, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&btSockAddr), sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));

        /* <--- never got so far --> */

        if (err)
        {
            DWORD wsaErr = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << "connect error = " << wsaErr << std::endl;

        }
        else
        {
            //err = shutdown(s, SD_BOTH);

            err = closesocket(s);
            if (err)
            {
                std::cout << "closesocket error = " << err << std::endl;
            }
        }

        WSACleanup();
        ///////////////Socket


        BOOL ok = BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication(authCallbackHandle);
        if (!ok)
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication Error" << err << std::endl; 
        }



        ok = BluetoothFindDeviceClose(btDeviceFindHandle);
        if (!ok)
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "BluetoothDeviceClose Error" << err << std::endl; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "BluetoothFindFirstDevice Error" << err << std::endl; 
    }


    std::cin.get();
}
```

I have made some few more observations:

- The authentication callback and the **BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx** function are working fine, there is no error given back.
- If I do not install the authentication callback (**BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx**) and therefore have to manually enter the PIN (the UI shows up automatically while trying to connect), **connect** function returns properly and everything works fine, too. I even got data (the recv part is omitted in this snippet).
- If I search and pair completely manually (Bluetooth Tray Icon -> Add Device), everything is fine, too. A service and a virtual serial port is installed. Data come via putty.

So somewhere between calling the authentication callback and end of the **connect** function something is going wrong. Maybe when trying to get a certain structure data via a pointer, which should not be NULL, plus offset.

Or am I doing something wrong? Is there something missing?
Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your function is using the wrong calling convention.  [According to MSDN, you need to use the `CALLBACK` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766822.aspx), as in:

```
BOOL CALLBACK auth_callback_ex(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS authParams)
```

Having the wrong calling convention will result in a stack mismatch on return, which could cause an access violation inside the MS Bluetooth code when it can't find its local variables.

Or it could result in the parameters to your function being all jumbled.  If `authParams` and `pvParam` are swapped, because the `cdecl` calling convention expects args pushed from right to left and `stdcall` pushes them left to right, you'd get `NULL` in `authParams`, and then `authParams->deviceInfo.Address` will try to read address `0x04`.

The compiler should have caught this.  Compile with maximum warnings turned on (`/W4`).  You'll have to ignore the warnings about unknown pragma, this is a [bug in the header which I'm reporting to Microsoft (misspelled `#pragma deprecated`)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678191/-pragma-deprecate-in-vc-headers-should-be-deprecated-with-a-final-d).

Unfortunately there's [a second bug in the header, much more serious, of not specifying the calling convention explicitly](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678193/), with the result that it will only work correctly on x86 (32-bit code) if `/Gz` is used.  Yuck!

---

Followup: In the SDK headers shipped with VS2013, both issues are fixed.

Comment: I like it, but my v7.0 SDK header file disgrees.  No CALLBACK/WINAPI/etc:           typedef BOOL (*PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_EX)(__in_opt LPVOID pvParam, __in PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams);

Comment: [So is there no way to add newline in here??]  So I only get a warning when I do add CALLBACK to the definition (even at /W1).

Comment: @alan: Can you check and see whether `pvParam` is NULL or not?  It should be NULL, because that's what you gave to `BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx`.  If `authParams` is NULL and `pvParam` is not, then the header file is wrong (wouldn't be the first bug in that file).

Comment: @alan: Actually, the header file is wrong.  Functions and function pointers being passed across DLL boundaries must always specify an explicit calling convention, otherwise they'll break when `/Gd`, `/Gr`, or `/Gz` are used.

Comment: @alan: Another bug filed: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678193/calling-convention-missing-from-bluetoothregisterforauthenticationex-callback-parameter-type  If you can determine whether it suddenly starts working with /Gz, that would be useful information (and confirm that stdcall is the correct calling convention).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That is a good point. This mismatch between MSDN and WinSDK v7.0 regarding calling convention I have been aware of, well, I have relied on the header.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I noticed your opened support ticket. How long, do you think, will it last until a patch will be released? It is urgent ;-)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I forgot to say that "authParams" is valid, I checked it while debugging. The call "BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx" is executed without any error and the callback is left. It crashes behind.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Indeed, it is the calling convention. Thanks a lot! Editing the 'BluetoothAPIs.h'  header, inserting '__stdcall', OR setting the calling convention globally (not recommended) to '/Gz' solves the problem.

Comment: @WDev: These things rarely get fixed before the next service pack.  Editing your local copy of `BluetoothAPIs.h` is the best short-term solution.  But do visit that bug report, vote for it, and mark it reproducable, since that will get it more attention.

Answer (score 0):

You have a null-pointer access somewhere. "Access violation reading location **0x00000004**" indicates that, as it is only 4 bytes away from zero.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, that is what I assume. But, if you take a look at the code, you will not findy any remaining null-pointer :-(. Everything is "initalized".

Comment: @WDev: Try stepping through the code and also `ZeroMemory` every struct you use.

Comment: All used structs (4) are either zero'ed before or all members are set explicitly. However, I just tried to zero them all, but no difference, still crash within **connect**. The debugger offers a disassembly of ntdll.dll at this point.

Comment: @WDev: Did you try stepping through the code and checking every variable in the "locals" window?

Comment: Yes, I did. After leaving _auth_callback_ex_ and before returning from **connect*, the applications crashes. The device, as described, shows up being authenticated and connected, though. So the process of authenticating and connecting seems to be successful.

Comment: @WDev: Well, if it's not your code (according to your words), then I'm out of ideas, sorry. :(

Comment: What debugger are you running this under?  You should be able to get a stack-trace at least at the time of the crash to show where the code is crashing.  If in VS, set Debug->Exceptions to "Thrown" then the program will stop when the crash happens -- then look at the stack.  Otherwise run in windbg.  Or...  Enough for now! :-)

Comment: @alanjmcf: I am using Visual Studio 2010. The debugger already stops automatically when this exception is thrown. Stack frame (main thread): app|ws2_32.dll|mswsock.dll|w2_32.dll|w2_32.dll|mswsock.dll|mswsock.dll|ntdll.dll|ntdll.dll. Nothing unusual, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of thoughts to share with you, but be advised that these are hunches.  I haven't compiled and debugged your code, although I commend you for posting a complete sample.

I think the crash may be within your authentication callback function, due to a '''NULL''' pointer dereference.

These lines:

```
response.bthAddressRemote = authParams->deviceInfo.Address;
response.authMethod = authParams->authenticationMethod; // == BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_LEGACY
```

will cause the message you describe, if you are running on 32-bit Windows, and '''authParams''' may be '''NULL''' -- in that case, '''deviceInfo''' contributes a zero offset (it is at the beginning of the '''BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS'''), and '''.Address''' does contribute an offset of 4 ('''NULL + 4 == 0x00000004'''), because it follows a '''DWORD''' and nothing else within the '''BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO''' layout.

Is it possible that '''authParams''' is NULL when your callback is called?

As another poster has already mentioned, this could be due to incorrect calling convention (lack of '''CALLBACK''' macro) -- causing otherwise correct parameters to mis-align with the positions the compiled code is reading.

The second thought was:

```
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDeviceInfo;
ZeroMemory(&btDeviceInfo, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));   //"initialize"

btDeviceInfo.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
```

Can be represented by:

```
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDeviceInfo = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO)};
```

According to the standard, this will zero the other fields of '''btDeviceInfo'''.

Comment: Hunnicutt: Thanks for your thoughts. Yes, I do also think it comes from dereferencing a (NULL pointer + offset). It is a 32 Bit application on Windows 64 Bit. "authParams" is not NULL but valid, I checked it while debugging. Regarding your second thought, you are right, saves two lines of code, initializing POD that way :-)

Comment: @WDev: x64 has a standardized calling convention (I think it's most similar to x86 fastcall), so the mismatch has no effect.  The offset will be `4` regardless of bitness, because `sizeof(DWORD)` is 4 bytes on every platform (OTOH `DWORD_PTR` gets longer on x64).

Answer (score -2):

Or write managed code and use my Bluetooth library 32feet.NET  Super simple.  http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Will it crash then -- if so there's something wrong on your PC...

Comment: -1: Nice spam...  If you are able to help this person program in C or C++, then comment.  Pushing to another language is probably b/c you can't help in C or C++.

Comment: 1) I've already left a comment giving C++ debugging advice (#8 in the list below).  2) Just in case its not clear, the 32feet.NET library is free.  3) Previous posters asking for C/C++ help have been happy to change using managed code. :-,)

Comment: @alanjmcf: Thanks for your given alternative but I would like to stick to C++, or rather C for the WinAPI ;-).

Comment: @Heath: Hopefully my note above answers your concern of span and hence the down-vote can be removed. :-)

Comment: @alanjmcf - nope.  The question was in C, and you recommended C#.  -1